# How to organise chain of async calls in RxJava2 way

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, rx-android, rx-java2

I have next code wrapped in AsyncTask class

```
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(mContext))
                    mIndicatorTable.sync().blockingGet();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    final MobileServiceList<IndicatorModel> results = mIndicatorTable.table().read(null).blockingGet();
                    if (isViewAttached()) {
                        getMvpView().refreshIndicatorList(results);
                        getMvpView().hideLoading();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        };
```

`mIndicatorTable.sync()` and `mIndicatorTable.table().read(null)` both returns `Single<Boolean>`. `mIndicatorTable.sync()` - syncing local storage with remote one, if network is unavailable then we just read from local storage using `mIndicatorTable.table().read(null)` when network is ready - we execute syncing and then read from local storage (we don't care if syncing canceled or interrupted). And after all we should call View to refresh RecycleView. How it can be implemented with RxJava2?

**#UPDATE**

Working version

```
getDataManager().syncAll()
     .onErrorResumeNext(Single.just(false))
     .flatMap(list -> toSingle(mIndicatorTable.getTable().read(null)))
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribe(results -> {
        if (isViewAttached()) {
            getMvpView().refreshIndicatorList(results);
            getMvpView().hideLoading();
        }
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rx-java make chaining async call easy by just calling [.flatMap()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).

```
mIndicatorTable.sync()
        .flatMap(new Function<Boolean, SingleSource<MobileServiceList<IndicatorModel>>>() {
            @Override
            public SingleSource<MobileServiceList<IndicatorModel>> apply(Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                return mIndicatorTable.table().read(null);
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(...)
```

But you want to proceed the `sync()` call in another thread and RecycleView could only be accessed from main thread. That's where rx-android come in handy. `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` instantiate the stream in another thread and `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` ensure that statements below this line (here, `.subscribe(...)`) are executed in the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for solution. But in this case `.sync` failed then `.read` never executed, I'm right?. In my case `.read` must be executed regardless of `.sync` result (failed or success)

Comment: In this case you can catch after sync: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html

Comment: Since `sync` is a `Single<Boolean>`, it's also possible that a failure is represented by a `False` value, not an error.

Comment: I used onErrorResumeNext to resume execution flow